# How can use Node.js Module?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I would insert crypto-price in my project: http://cryptotipsitalia.sytes.net/. Down to "Valore BTC"

I have BTC yet, I need ETH prince and I must use Node.js.
How can I use this library "https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-price" to have Ethereum Price?

Thanks

Comment: Install it using e.g. `npm` or `yarn`, use `require('crypto-price')` to include it in your file where you want to use it, and then use it accoring to the API. If you have a specific problem to one of those steps then describe what problem it is, what result you expect and what result you get instead, with a minimal code example that allows to reproduce the problem.

Comment: It looks like OP wants something that works in the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand your question for using this module you just need to reference it in your script/file as regular node.js modules are referenced, like:

```
var crypto = require('crypto-price');
```

Here you can see basic use of modules in nodejs:
https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_modules.asp

And also, more details about module you can find on your link above or here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-price

Answer (score 0):

At first, you need to install 'crypto-price'. You can do this by using npm or yarn. For example, run the following to install the package by using npm:

```
npm install crypto-price
```

Now do the following to get the conversion rate from BTC to ETH:

```
let price = require('crypto-price');

price.getCryptoPrice('BTC', 'ETH').then(obj => { 
    console.log(obj.price); // It will print ETH rate per BTC
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Hope you are looking for this.

Comment: Ok thanks, but how can take obj.price?
Document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = obj.price; doesn't work.

Comment: @Federicobanfi `Document.getElementById("x").innerHTML`  looks like client side code that runs in the browser and not server side code that runs using node.js. Anyway you should include a minimal, complete, and verifiable example with your question.